# Edit collection of BindingSource

Tags: vb.net, collections, datagridview, datasource, bindingsource

I have this situation:

I have a List or an Array (haven´t deciced which one is better for my purpose, but it doesn´t matter) of some objects (for example list of Persons). In my form there is a DataGridView where I want to see all persons and their attributes. Person´s attributes can be edited at a runtime and I want to see these changes immediatelly in DataGridView. I have used `BindingSource` for this:

```
Dim _persons As New List(Of Person)
Dim persons As BindingSource = New BindingSource()

persons.DataSource = _persons
myGridView.DataSource = persons
```

Now when I add/remove a person via BindingSource (persons) this works perfectly. This change I can see immediatelly. But what if I want to edit one person? Lets have this class:

```
Public Class Person

     Public Property FirstName As Integer
     Public Property SecondName As String
     Public Property Address As String

End Class
```

If I want to edit firstname I can do it this way:

```
 _persons(1).FirstName = "John"
```

But this is directly via list and not via BindingSource so this change will not take affect in the DataGridView. Is there a way how to do that via BindingSource to take affect this edit in DataGridView?

I am sorry but this is first time I working with BindingSource so this is maybe a stupid question. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should affect the `BindingSource` directly (not the `List` you used to create the BindingSource), that is:

```
DirectCast(persons(1), Person).FirstName = "John"
```